# React select option with multiple object values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to save multiple values in one select and saving it in useState to use it again somewhere else. but it's not working I only get undefined values in my console.log .

here is the code:

```
import * as React from "react";
function App() {
  const [option, setOption] = React.useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  const options = [
    {
      label: "first",
      value: { width: 10, height: 10 },
    },
    {
      label: "second",
      value: { width: 20, height: 20 },
    },
    {
      label: "third",
      value: { width: 30, height: 30 },
    },
  ];
  const selectHandler = (e) => {
    setOption(e.target.value);
  };

  console.log(option.width);
  console.log(option.height);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test!</h1>
      <select value={options.value} onChange={selectHandler}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.label}>{option.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I don't know if it's even possible...
thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you hoping the state will hold after changing the `select`? It looks like you want state to be an array of objects? If you want to select multiple options in your select you should also use the `multiple` attribute on the select element.

Comment: @Andy sorry I couldn't explain my question correctly, no I don't want to select multiple options, I want my state to store width and height when selecting one option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your values in the state in a wrong manner. I've made some changes to your select handler function which hopefully solves your problem:

```
import * as React from 'react';
function App() {
  const [option, setOption] = React.useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  const options = [
    {
      label: 'first',
      value: { width: 10, height: 10 },
    },
    {
      label: 'second',
      value: { width: 20, height: 20 },
    },
    {
      label: 'third',
      value: { width: 30, height: 30 },
    },
  ];
  const selectHandler = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    switch (e.target.value) {
      case 'first':
        setOption(options[0].value);
        break;
      case 'second':
        setOption(options[1].value);
        break;
      case 'third':
        setOption(options[2].value);
        break;
    }
  };

  console.log(option.width);
  console.log(option.height);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test!</h1>
      <select value={options.value} onChange={(e) => selectHandler(e)}>
        {options.map((option) => (
          <option key={option.label}>{option.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This is a big help, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a `value` attribute to each option. Assign it the option label.
2. In `selectHandler` use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to locate the object in the options array with a label that matches the option value, and then add its value property to state.
3. To log changes to state use `useEffect` to watch for those changes and *then* log the result (state updates are async so you wouldn't be able to log the change immediately).

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function Example({ options }) {

  const [option, setOption] = React.useState({
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  });

  const selectHandler = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    const found = options.find(obj => obj.label === value);
    if (found) setOption(found.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(option), [option]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Test!</h1>
      <select onChange={selectHandler}>
        {options.map(option => (
          <option
            key={option.label}
            value={option.label}
            >{option.label}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  );

}

const options=[{label:"first",value:{width:10,height:10}},{label:"second",value:{width:20,height:20}},{label:"third",value:{width:30,height:30}}];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example options={options } />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```